# Is it possible to open ContextMenu by left click?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So the question is how to open the context menu with the left click and work fine with command bindings and in the same way using MVVM.

I tried the first stack overflow method with style to open the context menu. It works, but the commands are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the first part of your question, the ContextMenu default opening mode is left click on its container, so you don't have to implement nothing special to achieve this.

```
<Button Height="30" Width="50" Content="Hello world!">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Hello" />
            <MenuItem Header="World!" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

About binding MenuItems with MVVM commands, the solution is quite tricky; since ContextMenu itself is not on the VisualTree, you cannot reference commands to bind with RelativeSource.
The way to solve this issue is create a custom BindingProxy, to link your DataContext with MenuItem

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And the final result will be......

```
<xmlns:local="MyDemoApp/.../..."> <!-- BindingProxy namespace -->

<Button Height="30" Width="50" Content="Hello world!">
    <Button.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Data="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" />
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Hello" Command="{Binding Data.MyFirstCommand, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="World!" Command="{Binding Data.MySecondCommand, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Using XAML**

The following XAML code will create a button that opens a context menu when you click it, either with the left or right mouse button:

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuOnLeftClick" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenuPlacementMode" Value="MousePoint" />
</Style>

<ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" />
</ContextMenu>
```

The `ContextMenuOnLeftClick` style sets the `ContextMenu` property of the button to the `ContextMenu` element. The `ContextMenuPlacementMode` property is set to `MousePoint`, which means that the context menu will be opened at the mouse pointer's location.

**Using C#**

The following C# code will also create a button that opens a context menu when you click it, either with the left or right mouse button:

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ContextMenu _contextMenu;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        _contextMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Item 1"));
        _contextMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Item 2"));

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Content = "Button";
        button.ContextMenu = _contextMenu;

        this.Content = button;
    }
}
```

This code creates a `ContextMenu` element and adds two `MenuItem` objects to it. The `ContextMenu` element is then assigned to the `ContextMenu` property of the `Button` object.

To open the context menu when the button is clicked, you can handle the `MouseDown` event of the button. In the `MouseDown` event handler, you can set the `IsOpen` property of the `ContextMenu` element to `true`.